# ios6: GameCenter shows wrong category (leaderboard)

Tags: ios6, game-center, gamekit, leaderboard

I have leaderboards with IDs "1", "2" and "3". "1" and "2" was submitted for current version of app which is on the appstore, "3" is a new one. Test device has values submitted for all  categories. To open Leaderboards from within app I use the following code:

```
    GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardController != NULL)
    {
        leaderboardController.category = GameMode != MAIN ? @"3" : @"1";
        leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
        leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
        [mainWindowController presentModalViewController:leaderboardController animated:YES];
    }
```

If works well on ios 5.0.1, 5.1.1 both for "3" and "1", but I have a strange issue on ios 6.0.1: when I try to open category "1" - no problem, but when I open "3" - Game Center usually shows just "leaderboard" screen with default category ("1") values.

Maybe this happens because my "3" category isn't "online" yet and when I release the new version of the app where "3" category will be included this problem will disappear? I tried to 
change "3" to "2":

```
leaderboardController.category = GameMode != MAIN ? @"2" : @"1";
```

and it worked for some time, and then again I see "leaderboard" screen with default category values.

Does anybody happen to have such a problem?

Update:
as a temporary solution I set category to nil to see all the categories.